# Declaring a variable inside an `if` statement in Java that is a different type depending on the conditional

Tags: java, declaration

I know, I know, there's a ton of simple answers that cover most cases for how to avoid this.

In my case, I want to use user-input info to create CPU players in a game. If the user chooses easy mode, then I want to declare and instantiate an instance of the `EasyPlayer` class. Otherwise, I want to declare and instantiate an instance of the `HardPlayer` class. Either way, the specific name of the variable needs to be "cpu" and the rest of the code operates on "cpu" indiscriminately. That is, all the differences in how these operate are built into their different classes, which subclass the `CpuPlayer` class.

So here's the code:

```
// Set the opponent.
if (difficulty == 0){
    EasyPlayer cpu = new EasyPlayer(num_rounds);
}
else{
    HardPlayer cpu = new HardPlayer(num_rounds);
}
```

This gives me the ever-annoying `cannot find symbol` error. From what I can read, everyone says you cannot make declarations inside a conditional like this due to scope problems and the possibility that it never occurs.

If so, what is the right way to alternatively declare a single variable as one of either of two different classes based on user input?

Comment: +1 for realizing that the solution you have here is insufficient and coming to SO for help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
CpuPlayer cpu;

if (difficulty == 0){
    cpu = new EasyPlayer(num_rounds);
}
else{
    cpu = new HardPlayer(num_rounds);
}
```

Comment: Ah. Major head-slapping moment. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to call only methods available to the CpuPlayer class, then perhaps a better design pattern to use is the **[Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)**. In your case, you would probably add a new class called *CpuStrategy*, and modify your CpuPlayer constructor to something like:

```
public CpuPlayer(CpuStrategy strategy, int num_rounds)
```

This makes the rest of your code easier to read and probably easier to maintain too. Here's what your original snippet of code would look like:

```
CpuPlayer cpu = new CpuPlayer(new CpuStrategy(difficulty), num_rounds);
```

We got rid of the if/else since the CpuStrategy class will handle the difference between difficulty levels. This also makes sense since you can abstract away the notion of "difficulty levels" from the meat of your program, which I assume is the game playing part.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the extra details. This is indeed a good re-design idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
CpuPlayer cpu; 
// Set the opponent.
if (difficulty == 0){
    cpu = new EasyPlayer(num_rounds);
} else{
    cpu = new HardPlayer(num_rounds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare it first, and then assign it.

```
// Set the opponent.
CpuPlayer cpu = null;
if (difficulty == 0){
    cpu = new EasyPlayer(num_rounds);
}
else{
    cpu = new HardPlayer(num_rounds);
}
if(cpu == null) throw new IllegalStateException();
```

Comment: The null assignment at the beginning seems unnecessary, as there is an ELSE to the IF conditional. As long as HardPlayer inherits from CpuPlayer, and HardPlayer doesn't throw any exceptions during construction, it would seem like the first and last line of the program are unnecessary. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SiddharthaShankar It's a habit - often times, you will end up with "this variable may not have been assigned" errors.

Comment: The null assignment and subsequent check aren't just unnecessary, they're harmful in that they turn a compile-time check into a runtime check. Without the initial assignment, any attempt to use `cpu` after the `else` clause will result in a compile-time error unless `cpu` had been assigned a value (in this case, one of two `new` instances) in all code branches. In other words, if there were ever a code branch that forgot to set value, the compiler would tell you (rather than having to throw a runtime exception).

Comment: @yshavit ideally, the best way to handle it would be `final CpuPlayer = CpuPlayerFactory.newCpuPlayer(difficulty);`

Comment: @corsiKa Yup, that or a ternary op: `CpuPlayer cpu = (difficulty == 0)? new EasyPlayer(num_rounds) : new HardPlayer(num_rounds)`.

Comment: The factory approach seems more robust, the ternary operator would work for this specific approach only i.e. only two difficulties.

Comment: @SiddharthaShankar @corsiKa The factory method has its pros and cons. It does mean that the logic for the difficulty-to-implementation belongs to the `CpuPlayer` (not in, say, the preferences component), and it means you can't use polymorphism for that mapping (since static methods can't be overridden).

Comment: EMS, Google for 'factory design pattern'.  I believe the solution presented by Laurence is what you really want, for now.  Note that CpuPlayer is either a superclass of both types of players or an interface that both types implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set the opponent.
CpuPlayer cpu;
if (difficulty == 0){
    cpu = new EasyPlayer(num_rounds);
} else{
    cpu = new HardPlayer(num_rounds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could tweak the design of your class structure. Make a parent class named Level and extend two child classes named EasyLevel and HardLevel.

```
class EasyLevel : public Level 
{

  //implementation specific to easy level
}

class HardLevel : public Level 
{
  //implementation specific to hard level
}
```

in your player class, add a modify the constructor to take a parameter of type Level.

```
class Player
{
  Level level;
  int rounds;

  public:
    Player (Level level, int num_rounds)
    {
       this.level = level;
       this.rounds = num_rounds;
    }

    play ()
    {
       // use level variable to invoke implementation specific to the set level, hard or easy. 
    }
}
```

This will make you class structure more extendable. As an example if you need to add another Level 'medium' in future, just need to extend from the parent class Level.

Answer (score 0):

```
CpuPlayer cpu = difficulty == 0
    ? new EasyPlayer(num_rounds)
    : new HardPlayer(num_rounds);
```

`cpu` can be made `final` if possible too.