# Java casting in if/else block

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm trying to take 2 values and cast them to Integer or Double, but I'm unable to do so in a simple manner as described below, because the variable declaration can't be done inside a block statement:

```
if (args.get(0) instanceof Integer) {
    Integer left = (Integer) args.get(0);
} else {
    Double left = (Double) args.get(0);
}

if (args.get(1) instanceof Integer) {
    Integer right = (Integer) args.get(1);
} else {
    Double right = (Double) args.get(1)
}

return left + right; // this is not allowed
```

Of course, a trivial solution would be to exhaust all 4 combinations:

```
if (args.get(0) instanceof Integer && args.get(1) instanceof Integer) {
    return ((Integer) args.get(0)) + ((Integer) args.get(1));
} else if ...
```

However, I assume there is a simple and well-known design pattern to achieve what I want much more eloquently.

Comment: Perfect link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205131/declaring-a-variable-inside-an-if-statement-in-java-that-is-a-different-type-d (related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463138/scope-of-variable-declared-inside-a-for-loop also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040556/declaring-a-variable-inside-of-if-else-construct)

Comment: Why not just cast everything to double?

Comment: @dbugger: Because I would like 2+3=5, not 2+3=5.0

Comment: @Tunaki. Thank you for your response. I'm however unable to see how the link you provided could help my case. Double and Integer are both derived from Number, but I can't add 2 instances of Number together with a binary operator. What am i missing?

Comment: Going through an awful lot of work to do something that is easily handled by formatting the result as needed.

Comment: well, what about 2.9 + 1.1. Should it be 4.0 or just 4?
and 3.0 + 1?
Also what are you going to return? an object?

Comment: I agree that the problem is trivially solved. However, as this problem seems general enough, I was curious if there  was a simple design pattern for it that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @bns. 2.9+1.1=4.0. The operators should act the same as in the Java language. And yes, I'm going to return an Object.

Comment: What happens if you get one Integer and one Double? How do you want to add that? If that is not the case you're after, just: 1) declare you variables with `Integer left_i = null, right_i = null; ` and `Double left_d = null, right_d = null;`; then, 2) parse them like you do with `if (args.get(0) instanceof ...)` and 3) return the result: `if(left_i != null) { return left_i + right_i;} return left_d + right_d;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to exhaust all 4 options, because only one of them results in an integer:

```
Number left = (Number)args.get(0);  // not sure if casting is necessary here
Number right = (Number)args.get(1); // since I don't know the type of your list
if (left instanceof Integer && right instanceof Integer) {
    // if both operands are Integer, return an Integer
    return left.intValue() + right.intValue();
} else {
    // if any of the operands is Double, the result must be Double
    return left.doubleValue() + right.doubleValue();
}
```